# How to run Python3 with mod option "-m" on package residing in different path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, package

How can we use **python3 -m** option to run on a package/module that resides in different directory rather than current working directory?

Suppose, my current working directory is "/tmp/dir_one"
And my python package resides in "/tmp/dir_two/package".

How to execute the following command from `/tmp/dir_one`?

> python3 -m dir_two.package.module

Answer (score 2):

For a module in `/tmp/foo` like:

`/tmp/foo/__main__.py`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('/tmp/foo/__main__.py: main')
```

`/tmp/foo/__init__.py`:

```
print('/tmp/foo/__init__.py: init')
```

The command

```
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/tmp/ python -m foo
```

Gives

```
/tmp/foo/__init_.py: init
/tmp/foo/__main__.py: main
```

[More about PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH)